# ansible - looping over no existing value

Tags: ansible

I'm gathering facts from cisco router and then I want to create ip address object in netbox as you can see below:

```
- name: gather facts
  cisco.ios.ios_facts:
   gather_subset: all
  register: result

- name: Add Interface IP address to Netbox
  netbox_ip_address:
    netbox_url: xxx
    netbox_token: xxx
    data:
      address: "{{ item.value.ipv4.0.address}}/{{ item.value.ipv4.0.subnet}}"
      assigned_object:
        name:  "{{ item.key }}"
        device: "{{ ansible_net_hostname }}"
    state: present
  with_dict: "{{ ansible_net_interfaces }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
```

So I'm looping over a dict variable - "ansible_net_interfaces" - which looks like this:

```
 "ansible_net_interfaces": {
                "GigabitEthernet1": {
                    "bandwidth": 1000000,
                    "description": "dgfh",
                    "duplex": "Full",
                    "ipv4": [
                        {
                            "address": "10.0.0.1",
                            "subnet": "24"
                        },
                        {
                            "address": "10.10.20.48",
                            "subnet": "24"
                        }
                    ],
                    "lineprotocol": "up",
                    "macaddress": "0050.56bf.9379",
                    "mediatype": "Virtual",
                    "mtu": 1500,
                    "operstatus": "up",
                    "type": "CSR vNIC"
                },
 "Port-channel1": {
                    "bandwidth": 1000000,
                    "description": "CCIE-TEST",
                    "duplex": null,
                    "ipv4": [],
                    "lineprotocol": "down",
                    "macaddress": "001e.bd55.92c0",
                    "mediatype": null,
                    "mtu": 1501,
                    "operstatus": "down",
                    "type": "GEChannel"
                },
```

And I have a problem when there is an interface without IP address:

```
 fatal: [xxx]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: list object has no element 0\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/playbooks/ios_facts.yml': line 37, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Add Interface IP address to Netbox\n      ^ here\n"}
```

How can I change that line:

```
address: "{{ item.value.ipv4.0.address}}/{{ item.value.ipv4.0.subnet}}"
```

so there will be no error if item.value.ipv4.0.address doesn't exist?

Comment: Will this work for two addresses? You take just one. And what kind of result do you want to assign to "address"? "null/null"? Or do you want to omit the `netbox_ip_address` task in that case?

Comment: No it doesn't work for two addresses. But you're right, it would be good if it could. I don't want to omit the whole task. Only this interface without ip address.

Comment: So the task fails because the length of the array is 0, and you're trying to get a value that doesn't exists. What you could do is add `when: item.value.ipv4|length` (meaning it will only run if `True`/`1`, you could of course add `item.value.ipv4|length >= 1` if you prefer it for readability etc , though this will skip the task when the length of `item.value.ipv4` is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Use [*with_subelements*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html#ansible-builtin-subelements-traverse-nested-key-from-a-list-of-dictionaries). This will automatically omit empty subelement lists, .e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          name: {{ item.0.key }}
          address: {{ item.1.address }}/{{ item.1.subnet }}
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ ansible_net_interfaces|dict2items }}"
        - value.ipv4
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: |-
    name: GigabitEthernet1
    address: 10.0.0.1/24

  msg: |-
    name: GigabitEthernet1
    address: 10.10.20.48/24
```

---

Use [*loop_control*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables) if you want to use the first address from the list only (In the comment to the question you say: 'it doesn't work for two addresses')

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          name: {{ item.0.key }}
          address: {{ item.1.address }}/{{ item.1.subnet }}
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ ansible_net_interfaces|dict2items }}"
        - value.ipv4
      loop_control:
        extended: true
      when: ansible_loop.index == 1
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: ...
  msg: |-
    name: GigabitEthernet1
    address: 10.0.0.1/24

skipping: ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the dictionary items without an IP address by the use of `dict2items`, `selectattr` and `items2dict`:

```
with_dict: "{{ ansible_net_interfaces | dict2items | selectattr('value.ipv4') | items2dict }}"
```

Example:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars:

    mydict:
      "GigabitEthernet1":
        "bandwidth": 1000000
        "description": "dgfh"
        "duplex": "Full"
        "ipv4":
          - "address": "10.0.0.1"
            "subnet": "24"
          - "address": "10.10.20.48"
            "subnet": "24"
        "lineprotocol": "up"
        "macaddress": "0050.56bf.9379"
        "mediatype": "Virtual"
        "mtu": 1500
        "operstatus": "up"
        "type": "CSR vNIC"
      "Port-channel1":
        "bandwidth": 1000000
        "description": "CCIE-TEST"
        "duplex": null
        "ipv4": []
        "lineprotocol": "down"
        "macaddress": "001e.bd55.92c0"
        "mediatype": null
        "mtu": 1501
        "operstatus": "down"
        "type": "GEChannel"

    mydictwithip: "{{ mydict | dict2items | selectattr('value.ipv4') | items2dict }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: mydictwithip
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answers were very helpful!
I did it this way:

```
- name: Add Interface IP address to Netbox
  netbox_ip_address:
    netbox_url: xxx
    netbox_token: xxx
    data:
      address: "{{ item.value.ipv4.0.address}}/{{ item.value.ipv4.0.subnet}}"
      assigned_object:
        name:  "{{ item.key }}"
        device: "{{ ansible_net_hostname }}"
    state: present
  with_dict: "{{ ansible_net_interfaces }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
  when: item.value.ipv4.0.address is defined
```

And it works although I'm curious wheter 'ipv4': [] is really undefined element?

```
skipping: [sandbox-iosxe-recomm-1.cisco.com] => (item={'key': 'Loopback21', 'value': {'description': None, 'macaddress': None, 'mtu': 1514, 'bandwidth': 8000000, 'mediatype': None, 'duplex': None, 'lineprotocol': 'up', 'operstatus': 'up', 'type': None, 'ipv4': []}})
```

I'm wondering also if there is a way of looping over IPv4 in case of two or more definded ip addresses on Interface.
For example with dict like this:

```
"ansible_net_interfaces": {
            "GigabitEthernet1": {
                "bandwidth": 1000000,
                "description": "Configured with Netconf",
                "duplex": "Full",
                "ipv4": [
                    {
                        "address": "10.0.0.1",
                        "subnet": "24"
                    },
                    {
                        "address": "10.11.11.11",
                        "subnet": "24"
                    },
                    {
                        "address": "10.10.20.48",
                        "subnet": "24"
                    }
                ],
                "lineprotocol": "up",
                "macaddress": "0050.56bf.9379",
                "mediatype": "Virtual",
                "mtu": 1500,
                "operstatus": "up",
                "type": "CSR vNIC"
            },
            "GigabitEthernet1.10": {
                "bandwidth": 1000000,
                "description": null,
                "duplex": null,
                "ipv4": [
                    {
                        "address": "1.1.1.1",
                        "subnet": "24"
                    }
                ],
                "lineprotocol": "up",
                "macaddress": "0050.56bf.9379",
                "mediatype": null,
                "mtu": 1500,
                "operstatus": "up",
                "type": "CSR vNIC"
            },
            "GigabitEthernet2": {
                "bandwidth": 1000000,
                "description": "Configured by RESTCONF Demo 2",
                "duplex": "Full",
                "ipv4": [],
                "lineprotocol": "down",
                "macaddress": "0050.56bf.ea76",
                "mediatype": "Virtual",
                "mtu": 1500,
                "operstatus": "down",
                "type": "CSR vNIC"
            },
```